# Using RestSharp to call API that Works in POSTMAN but not in RestSharp

Tags: c#, postman, restsharp

Using API provided I am trying to retrieve some data, the API works flawlessly on POSTMAN using OAuth1.0. When i then look to implement this in C# using RestSharp it works on one of the API and not on the rest, replying with an authorisation error.

API example:

```
/getData
```

-Works on POSTMAN and RestSharp (Since this works in RestSharp i assume OAuth is correct, but i will provide me code.

```
/getData/search?Name=john
```

-Works on POSTMAN only, RestSharp returns Authentication error, key and tokens have not changed.

```
        const string consumerKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        const string consumerSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        const string token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        const string tokenSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        Uri baseUrl = new Uri("https://test.com/api");

        var client = new RestClient(baseUrl)
        {
            Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(consumerKey,consumerSecret,token,tokenSecret)
        };
        client.FollowRedirects = false;

        var request = new RestRequest("getData",Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");

        request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content;
```

I have been staring at this for hours trying everything i can think of and google, but nothing seems to be working. Any Advice??
Only thing i can think off is does there need to be a time stamp/ signature, but then wouldnt none of the API work in RestSharp.

Comment: Use Fiddler to look at both requests.  Figure out why they're different and adjust your code accordingly

Comment: Using fiddler and windiff i cannot see any obvious differences, the authentication details contain the same structure. Should i be looking for something in particular